# Loop through tables collection in MS Word from MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to do some adjustments to all tables in MS Word document and I have this code:

```
Dim oTbl As Table

For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With oTbl.Range.Next
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then .Delete
  End With
Next
```

This normally works when I run it from MS Word but when I try to run it from MS Excel I encounter

> Type 13 mismatch error.

Does anyone know why? And how to make this work from Excel?

Thanks!

Comment: In which line do get the error? • Is this all you run from Excel? The code cannot run as it is from Excel alone. Please show the complete relevant code part. Have you set a reference to Microsoft Word or are you using Late Binding? `wdWithInTable` only works with a reference set. Also Excel does not know `ActiveDocument` without referencing the Word instance.

Comment: I get the error in this line: For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables. I have set the reference and I'm using Early Binding in this case. This part of the code is separated sub that is called by another one on multiple occasions. I have tried referencing the Word instance with GetObject(, "Word.Application"), but that does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference Word from Excel. Here is one approach.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExampleDelete()
    const wdWithInTable as long = 12
    Dim wrd As Object, doc As Object, tbl As Object
    Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set doc = wrd.documents.Open("C:\Users\Ryan\desktop\Example.docx") 'Update your path here

    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        With tbl.Range.Next
            If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then .Delete
        End With
    Next

    'Do other actions here...maybe save?
End Sub
```

Comment: Worth to mention that if the Word file is already open in a Word instance then checkout `Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")` to get the already open word instance.

Comment: Yup, also can use a static object if is constantly referencing the same object to speed up obtaining the reference too

Comment: Thank you your code helped me to solve the problem, also explanation from @Pᴇʜ was very helpful. I did not reference the MS Word application instance.